# How can I make hybrid(iOS and Android) project using RoboVM??

Tags: robovm

I"m looking for the way make hybrid application on RoboVM using Inteilij RoboVM plugin. Common Java logics,project for ios,project for android app. Any infos??

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of RoboVM

http://robovm.com/get-started/